# Usar do while dentro de outro do while no PHP

Tags: php, mysql

O que acontece no meu código PHP é o seguinte: faço uma consulta no banco de dados e com isso um DO WHILE (enquanto essa consulta retornar registros), exibe algumas informações na tela (baseado na consulta, claro). Até aí, tudo certo. Porém preciso agora, dentro deste DO WHILE, colocar outro, para percorrer outra consulta e 'printar' outros valores. Preciso isso dentro de outro DO WHILE por que a nova consulta será sempre de acordo com o ID gerado na primeira consulta, ou seja, diferente para cada iteração. Testes de diversas maneiras mas não rodou ou obtive erro. Como posso ter um "do while" e dentro deste, após o "do", ter outro?

Ex:

```
do{

      do{
      while($consulta2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados2));

while($consulta = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
```

Comment: O que sua consulta de `$dados` retorna? Adicione as consultas `sql` que você faz.

Comment: Adiciona o código inteiro.

Comment: Bom dia amigo , poste aqui os códigos de suas 2 consultas . Um while dentro de outro  eu particularmente não recomendo . No caso ,acredito que fazer um join entre as tabelas seria melhor.

Comment: Se entendi bem sua duvida você pretende utilizar um while dentro de outro para poder fazer consulta em duas tabelas distintas que possuem id's relacionados certo?
Se for isso, creio que a melhor alternativa ao invés de se utilizar multiplos whiles seria a utilização de "Joins" diretamente no seu SQL Não irei aprofundar muita na explicação do uso de Join, creio que este tópico deve resolver seu problema: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join) Boa Sorte!

Comment: Iterar uma consulta dentro de outra? Just ... don't ... do ..... it ....

Answer (score 1):

Seus laços estão corretos. Talvez o erro  ocorra por estar usando

```
do {
    // Código
} while( ... );
```

No lugar de

```
while( ... ) {
    // Código
}
```

Pois usando `do .. while`, o laço é executado pelo menos uma vez, o que pode gerar erro se a consulta não retornar nada. Além do mais é necessário executar `$consulta = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados)` antes do `do` para garantir que vai ter algum valor na variável `$consulta`.

Recomendo mudar seu código para

```
while($consulta = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados)) {
    // Código
    while($consulta2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados2)) {
        // Código
    }
}
```

Quando adiciona um `while` dentro do outro você aumenta o processamento exponencialmente.

Ex: se tiver 15 registros, vai executar o laço interno 15 vezes, ficando péssimo em questão de performance.